# Redefining existing columntypes

Tags: tables, color

I have a LaTeX document which is very table-heavy (at least 100 tables in various sizes), in which I have used the standard columntypes `l`, `c` and `r`. Now I've changed my mind about how I'd like the tables to look as I didn't prioritize this over making the tables in the first place.

**More specifically I want to change the color of the text in each table.**

My question is, is there any way to redefine or "`renewcolumntype`" columntypes like it's possible to `renewcommand` commands so I don't have to go through the insane amount of tables I have to write my redefinition manually?

The tables i have are very standard issue, so I don't see how a MWE would help here.
They all look like this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \rowcolors{2}{}{grey!40}
    \colorbox{tablecolor}{%
        \begin{tabular}{lrr}
            columnheader 1 & columnheader 2 & columnheader 3 \\\midrule
            x              & y              & z              \\
            x              & y              & z              \\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:label}
\end{table}
```

LaTeX isn't happy when I try this:

```
\newcolumntype{l}{>{\color{newcolor}}l}
\newcolumntype{c}{>{\color{newcolor}}c}
\newcolumntype{r}{>{\color{newcolor}}r}
```

But is fine with this:

```
\newcolumntype{u}{>{\color{newcolor}}l}
\newcolumntype{i}{>{\color{newcolor}}c}
\newcolumntype{o}{>{\color{newcolor}}r}
```

Although the latter works as intended, it means I have to go through all the tables and change the columntypes in every single one.

Comment: If you want to change the color of the text of all the tables, maybe you could use a hook of the environment `{tabular}` : `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\color{red}}` (in recent versions of LaTeX).

Comment: Such a simple solution for a problem i made so difficult. It works like it should. If I could mark it as an answer I would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the text of all the tables, maybe you could use a hook of the environment `{tabular}` : `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\color{red}}` (in recent versions of LaTeX).